# Where can I ask a question about coding platforms?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to write a small application to help me write modifications for a game I enjoy. I'm thinking of asking the community for recommendations of a good language to use, or which of a few options I'm toying with would be good. Benefits/disadvantages for packages from those who know a bit more.

My instinct would be to ask on Stack Overflow, but it's a question fishing for information about the benefits and disadvantages of different coding platforms rather than a question about solving a specific coding problem. I don't want to fall foul of site rules. Which Stack Exchange site is it best placed on?

Comment: You can't ask for recommendations or opinions at most of the SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/295232), recommendation questions are off-topic for most Stack Exchange sites:

> **Good questions:**
>
> ...
>
> - Don't ask for product or service recommendations. (except for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/))

You're basically asking for software recommendations, but one that is explicitly off-topic according to [this post on their meta site](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/23377).

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A **purpose** — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some **objective requirements** — a minimum set of features

(from their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: I didn't put specifics here because, to be frank, I was scared that if I did I would be seen as asking a question by stealth and I'm so paranoid of getting marked down for asking an inappropriate question. These sites have an excellent defence against the wrong kind of question but as a result suffer from the same problem that wikis often have. Namely some overzealous users too keen to mark down new users for infraction of the rules. I was going to state the purpose (namely, to put quickly together an app with a few boxes for editing specific coding files and a pixel editing screen).

Comment: Actually, you *should* put the specifics, as stated in the tag wiki excerpt: *Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site. Please phrase your question explicitly as a site recommendation, or it might be closed as blatantly off-topic.*

Comment: It's so restrictive as a new user I don't want to be on minus points before I've even got anywhere.

Comment: Questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332203/295232) are swiftly downvoted, closed and deleted *because they're not site recommendations*. Your question is clearly recognizable as a site recommendation even if you didn't tag it as such :)

Comment: Ah. Interestingly "Site recommendation" was not a tag suggestion that came up in the suggestions. I'll make sure to change that.- Looks like someone has done it for me.

Comment: So would you say, on balance, that this was an ok question for Stack Overflow if I gave details of what I wanted to do and what I wanted from a coding platform?

Comment: Nope, recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. I think a question like this is better off on Quora or Reddit, but I have no personal experience with those sites.

Comment: Eh? but according to the top rated answer:Good software recommendation requests have two components:

A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features. Which I would be stating. I feel like its not even clear on here between users whether packages can be recommended or not. Quora is not a place to get answers it's a place for people to be snarky and opinionated and I'm fairly sure Reddit is quite a sharkpit too. One of the reason I want to ask in one of this suite of sites is that, relatively speaking, people are actually helpful.

Comment: "Benefits/disadvantages for packages from those who know a bit more" - that's really subjective. If you can morph your question into objective requirements, it could indeed work.

Comment: I was vague on here because I don't need to ask the question here. As it is I feel some horde of **overzealous** **Stackites** is just going to give me a pile of minuses that will make this site harder to use.

Comment: If we continue posting back-and-forth comments, we'll eventually get a link. But I'm not sure if I have more information to offer. I do have some reputation on Software Recommendations but I'm hesitant to make hard statements; I don't even have the reputation to vote to close there.

Comment: We're told to avoid extended discussions in comments and to use chat instead and yet it costs reputation to chat!!! That's surely a flaw in the system. Only way to earn reputation to start with seems to be questions so you're left stuck on the starting blocks if you don't have any decent questions.

Comment: @TimothyLeeRayner If you can rephrase the question in terms of *how to do it* rather than *what tool to use to do it*, it might work. This is the difference between "how do I accomplish X in language Y?" (answers to which are likely to suggest third-party resources such as toolkits; "you can use AcmeXyz this way: ...") and, say, "what toolkits for language Y will allow me to do X?". It can seem a subtle difference, but when you come at it from the perspective of *creating lasting value* not just for yourself but also others potentially years from now, it gets easier to understand.

Comment: @TimothyLeeRayner As for earning reputation, you can do that in other ways. A simple way is to make constructive edits to other peoples' posts on sites that are of interest to you. It's not that hard to earn a few hundred rep that way, which will get you past almost all of the new user limitations and then some. Each community-reviewed and accepted edit earns you 2 rep, so just ten such edits will get you past the threshold for the [talk in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) privilege.